# Installing html_quickform2 with EasyPHP

Tags: php, pear, easyphp

I am using the most recent version of EasyPHP (a PHP 5.5 installation) as of this writing and it does not have Pear installed. That wasn't a problem until I read about html_quickform2 which seemed like a useful utility but I couldn't figure out how to add it to my project. It's installable via Pear but that's not included with EasyPHP anymore and I'm not sure how to set it up.

Does anyone know how to do this? Otherwise, is there a simple PHP library that allows me to just drop a couple of PHP files into my application instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [installation instructions](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php) on the PEAR website.

Comment: Thanks buddy- wish you had been here a month ago! Although necessity brought me over to redbean which served my purposes brilliantly.